# Correct way of throwing exceptions with developer info

Tags: python, exception

Currently I'm throwing exceptions that I read via log files.
The log files contain the object in this case, so that I can easily find out what happened.

I'm wondering if this is best practice.
Would I be better of creating custom exceptions and provide no message?

For example:

```
FailedToSendSimDataUsageNotification
InvalidSimDataUsageResponse
SimDataUsageRequestFailed
```

Currently I use this:

```
raise Exception('Could not send data usage warning for: %s' % (subscription.subscription_number))
raise Exception('Could not collect SIM data usage, got no valid response for: %s' % (subscription.subscription_number))
raise Exception('Failed to collect SIM data usage for: %s' % (subscription.subscription_number))
```

I just implemented Sentry and I'm wondering if this is the right way to log the errors, since sentry already provides the variables used (such as subscription_number).

Comment: The advantage of custom exceptions is that you can very selectively catch them in `try..except` handlers. They don't make too much of a difference if you're just logging them. It's still helpful to have a formally declared inventory of all possible kinds of errors that may happen in your app, if only to standardise the error messages in a central place, instead of re-typing them everywhere they're thrown.

Comment: Do you recommend still putting the subscription_number in the message?
For example:

`raise SimDataUsageRequestFailed(subscription.subscription_number)`

Comment: Sure, concrete values are useful in exception messages. You just need to be careful how you may expose those messages, if that information is confidential.

Comment: Thank you.
I will follow your recommendation, it seems like a proper way to do it.